# NSDateFormatter not working

Tags: nsdateformatter

Ok I feel kind of dumb asking this, but any idea why this is not working:

```
 {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"mmmm dd, yyyy"];

        NSDate *myDateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:creditDate.text];
         NSLog(@"%@", myDateFromString);
        [self.credit setCertificationDate: myDateFromString];
    }
```

It returns null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format and string don't match because "m" is minute and "M" is month. So "August 18 2012" can't be interpreted, take "MMMM dd yyyy" instead You can check formats at [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

I always set a locale explicitly:

```
  NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
  [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
  [usLocale release];
```

As long as you don't parse month names, it doesn't matter if your real locale is en_US if supplying an explicit format string.

Some more hints:

- Use a hard coded strings for testing to rule out that the supplied date is wrong.
- Try easier formatter strings like without time or month as number to isolate the erroneous part.
- If it is still not working,you can use NSDateFormatter's getObjectValue:forString:range:error: to get more detailed information about the error.

Comment: Even more bizarre: when I hard code a text date like this:   NSDate *myDateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:@"9/1/2013"];
             NSLog(@"%@", myDateFromString); I still get null

Comment: I am on the right track! I changed the format and I got it to finally read... i set it to  [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY"]; it's reading it as 2012-12-23 07:00:00 +0000

Comment: I should have seen it, had the same bug months ago. I updated my answer and deleted my own comments to provide an answer in a row