# NSDateFormatter dateFromString gives the wrong date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

I've already tried the suggestions in other posts similar to this with no avail. Here is the situation:

I have an NSString like this:

```
Fri November 18, 2011
```

and I am trying to convert that to a date like this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EE MMMM d, YYYY"];
    NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: dateString];
```

But the resulting myDate variable holds this:

```
2010-12-31 00:00:00 +0000
```

Does anyone have any idea why the wrong date is being picked out from the dateFromString? The string is November 18th, the converted date is December 31st...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should log the value of dateString to make sure it's what you expect. Also try using "EEE" instead of "EE", "dd" instead of "d", and "yyyy" instead of "YYYY" to rule out any oddities there (although what you have seems like it should work)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to use `yyyy` for the year, not `YYYY`.

From the [Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of "Week of Year"), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

And to be correct you also have to change `EE` to `EEE`.  Though they yield the same result in my test.

Comment: Changing the YYYY to yyyy and EE to EEE worked perfectly - thanks!

Comment: this worked!!  but there's something unusual going on.. i used this format to print all dates in year 2013 .. only Dec 29,30,31 2013 were displayed as Dec,29,30,31 2014..weird !!?

Comment: Worked perfectly! You are a complete star... thank you for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need "EEE MMMM d, YYYY" i.e. triple E as format string. If this does not work, I recommend using hard coded strings with easier dates and formats to break down the problem. See for example [NSDateFormatter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103150/nsdateformatter-not-working/7103194#7103194) for more hints on that topic.

Comment: Changing the EE to EEE was part 1 of the problem solved - thanks very much!