# dateFromString making wrong date

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am definitely not new to NSDateFormatter or NSDate but this has completely stumped me. How in the world am I getting fire date wrong?

```
NSDateFormatter *firedateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [firedateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a EEE dd MMM, YYYY"];
    [firedateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

    NSDate *fireDate1 = [firedateFormat dateFromString:@"5:30 AM Sat 27 Oct, 2012"];

    NSLog(@"fireDate1: %@ ...", fireDate1);

OUTPUT:
fireDate1: 2011-12-31 10:30:00 +0000 ...
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8186833/467105.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a smaller error, switch the YYYY to yyyy

```
NSDateFormatter *firedateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[firedateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a EEE dd MMM, yyyy"];
[firedateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

NSDate *fireDate1 = [firedateFormat dateFromString:@"5:30 AM Sat 27 Oct, 2012"];

NSLog(@"fireDate1: %@ ...", fireDate1);
```

Output: `fireDate1: 2012-10-27 10:30:00 +0000 ...` (Date in GMT)

A great reference for all Date Formatters http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/