# iOS 'dateFromString' Returning One Year Off

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am using the NSDateFormatter's dateFromString, yet when it is given the string '2013-03-06' it spits out an NSDate of '2012-03-06 00:00:00 CST'.  The time is of no importance. I have the date format set to be exactly the same between the input and output.

I have an object which gets a date set using the code:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate* currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
[self setMyValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:currentDate]];
```

And then this value is later used to to set the date on a UIDatePicker:

```
NSDate *date = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

date = [dateFormat dateFromString:myFilter.myValue];

[datePicker setDate:date animated:YES];
```

Any pointers on where I am erring would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change YYYY in the format to yyyy.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186833/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-gives-the-wrong-date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `yyyy` and not `YYYY`.

From [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html):

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year
>   whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO
>   year-week calendar

Answer (score 1):

Change YYYY in the format to yyyy.

Answer (score -1):

Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`, to get the zero error while changing 'YEARS'.

Comment: What value does this answer have over the other two answers?