# Objective C Timestamp

Tags: ios, objective-c, unix-timestamp

I have found numerous timestamp conversions and they all work but the thing is, when I put my code to the text form of the date, I always come out 4 months ahead.

This is pulling the current Day of Week, Date and Time.  I have it set this way cause I select the day with a DateTime Picker.  This is just my viewDidLoad to pull today's date.

```
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMMM dd, YYYY, hh:mm aa"];
NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
date.text = prettyVersion;
```

Now comes the timestamp conversion to take prettyVersion to timeIntervalSince1970

```
NSDate *startdates = [dateFormat dateFromString:prettyVersion];
NSLog(@"Timestamp %0.0f",[startdates timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

NSLog outputs "Timestamp 1356317580" which when converted is Mon, 24 Dec 2012 02:53:00 GMT

Now I can do this

```
          NSLog(@"Timestamp2  %0.0f",[myDate timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

and get the right timestamp.

So where am i messing up at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has already been answered here:  [NSDateFormatter dateFromString gives the wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186833/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-gives-the-wrong-date)

But the gist of it is in your date dateFormat you should use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY".

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm aa"];
```

And then for me it would format to "Sunday, September 15, 2013, 07:24 PM" which is what it was when I ran this to test.

Comment: I appriciate that, I guess when i was browsing the lower case y's did not catch my eyes. The simple things, i miss., thanks.